# Pdo select query returns column values in inappropriate way(unicode issue)

Tags: php, mysql, unicode, pdo

I try to retrieve all data from db table with pdo with this code:

```
$stmt = $this->_db->query("SELECT * FROM ki_cities");
         $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         return $result;
```

It returns following array:

> [{"id":"1","city":"\u10d7\u10d1\u10d8\u10da\u10d8\u10e1\u10d8"},{"id":"2","city":"\u10e5\u10e3\u10d7\u10d0\u10d8\u10e1\u10d8"},{"id":"3","coty":"\u10d1\u10d0\u10d7\u10e3\u10db\u10d8"}]

The problem is that actually column citie's values are city:"თელავი", city:"თბილისი", city:"გორი". (These are Georgian words).

I guess the problem is in unicode. P.S. Collation in database is set to utf8_unicode_ci(this is multilingual unicode in mysql).

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I missed one step, I returned this data with json and problem was in json_encode();